# Как в js остановить воспроизведение звука?

Tags: javascript, аудио, web-audio

Есть много тем, где описывается решение с проблемой остановки звука js класса Audio, но всё не то.

stop() отсутствует и не работает.

pause() лишь приостанавливает звук. А мне нужно, чтобы при следующем нажатии play() он начинал играть с самого начала.

volume = 0; Только мютит звук и всё. С самого начала он играть не будет.

Так как остановить звук?

Answer (score 1):

Если б гуглили "как задать воспроизведение аудио сначала", то бы сразу попался нужный ответ. А вопрос как остановить воспроизведение возвращает не те результаты. Команды **audio.stop()** не существует наверно потому, что её регистрация отнята бы время у разработчиков браузеров, (и деньги пришлось бы за это платить) но смысла пока мало, т. к., вместо этого можно **audio.pause(); audio.currentTime = 0;** и неважно, в какой последовательности. И ещё - если нужно, чтобы при следующем нажатии play() он начинал играть с самого начала, то наверно лучше перед началом воспроизведения и вставить **audio.currentTime = 0;**

```js
playbutton.onclick = function(){
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  audio.play();
}
```

**

А вот функция **audio.load()** для этой цели не очень хорошая, т. к., она по новой загружает мета- и аудиоданные из файла, из-за чего контрольная панель плеера передёргивается, а если на сайте много посетителей, то это ещё может усилить нагрузку на сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Можете так сделать.

```
sound.currentTime = 0;
sound.pause();
```

Comment: наоборот же ...

Answer (score -1):

Нашел хороший вариант: пустая функция load().

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]